# Javers throws exception when property is null

Tags: java, javers

I have this issue where, if a property of a composite is null (note it's not the ID), Javers throws an exception:

```
JaversException PROPERTY_ACCESS_ERROR: error getting value from property 'Method User getPersonEntity; //declared in: HibernateProxy_$$_javassist_356' on target object of type 'HibernateProxy_$$_javassist_356', cause: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
```

or

```
JaversException PROPERTY_ACCESS_ERROR: error getting value from property 'Method List getAddress; //declared in: ... **Object property of the audited object**, cause: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
```

So, imagine the following structure:

User contains Person, which contains Address - all objects with their own properties.

If I commit a User object, if either Person or Address has a null property, Javers fails with the above error.

How does Javers handle null properties? Can it be configured to just not log a null property or to log it as null? I can't see a reason why it should throw an exception when a property is null?! There doesn't seem to be any documentation about how null properties are handled.

Answer (score 1):

JaVers deals with nulls without any problems, but your getter didn't return null but thrown exception.
Seems your object is a Hibernate dynamic proxy and cant'b be initialized.

Comment: It's a bit weird that this happens since the Hibernate Session is still open. It should be able to lazy load the object without an issue. The JaVers error doesn't give me much info either, just that the property is null. So it's not clear what actually happens. Is there a way to enable debug level logging for JaVers to see more info of what's happening?

Comment: JaVers said "PROPERTY_ACCESS_ERROR error getting value from property" and it's true. Your getter thrown an exception, you should face it:)

Comment: try Hibernate unproxy hook, see https://javers.org/documentation/spring-integration/#hibernate-unproxy-hook

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I'd need. We unfortunately don't use Spring, really old app. Do you think it'd work if I add the package and only use that class?